# How does Playit app prevent videos from playing in other media players? What technology does it use

Tags: android, video-streaming, playback

There is a website pdisk.net and whatever the video we upload from our computer to the site and share the link to view it, the videos open only in Playit android app. Only first 15 seconds can be viewed after that a screen appears showing "to play the video, install Playit app from playstore". What is happening to the videos in the backend when we upload on pdisk.net website? I think the site is owned by Playit app only. I noticed that the uploaded videos use final url a6.hentai.com...etc to stream the videos which can be streamed fully using the app only.
Can someone tell if the videos are encoded or encrypted backend and the app is made to decrypt the videos? Is such thing possible?
'''no code req.'''

Comment: This video tricks have been around for a long time now https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/223666/why-downloaded-videos-by-vidmate-can-only-be-played-using-playit it is just annoying and trying to gather some money or personal data I guess, never payed or installed those. whenever I see them I move on :) no need to take the risk

Answer (score 0):

In their [FAQ page](https://www.playit.app/playit-faq), they have mentioned that:

> Video downloaded by Apps uses Smart Muxer technology.Smart Muxer is a
> unique technology developed by PLAYit, can merge the video and audio
> within seconds without any extra recoding and storage. It’s really
> workable when there are some videos have no build-in audio and need to
> be merged in the devices with low configurations. Due to the unique
> technology, the video can be only played by PLAYit and the other
> main-stream players can’t support. And videos shared to social apps
> can also be opened in PLAYit.

I found one of the discussion in [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/androidapps/comments/nmc8r8/playit_mp4_extension_encrypted_video_container/h01zwh2/?context=8&depth=9), as mentioned by one of the users:

> They encrypt the normal mp4 video in some kind of way which enables
> them to limit the playback to their app.

As for documentation, there is not much available online. But found [this feature request](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=154516) in VLC forum.